# How do I debug why eslint is not working correctly with vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm using vscode and eslint is running but it's not finding errors in certain files that it finds in others in the same project.

Is there some way to debug this? Like an option for more verbose output that will show me where it's getting its configuration for each file while running inside vscode?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way I've found of diagnosing ESLint problems is opening the tray at the bottom of the screen, clicking the Output tab, and selecting the ESLint debug feed from the dropdown at the top right corner of the tray. This will report what problems ESLint encounters as it loads and tries to lint your code. You might have to open a file of the type you're trying to lint to see all the output problems.

You can also open this from the command palette by pressing `Cntl + Shift + P` and then typing `ESLint: Show Output Panel`.